# how to align the environment description so that it mixed with text

Tags: lists

I want to produce the following paragraph:
[image]

But when tried the following codes:

```
{\bf 8.}  
\begin{description}
\item[(a)] Show that $\mathbb{R}$ has the greatest lower bound property.
\item[(b)] Show that $\inf\{1/n\mid n\in\mathbb{Z}_+\}=0.$
\item[(c)] Show that given $a$ with $0<a<1,$ $\inf\{a^n\mid     n\in\mathbb{Z}_+\}=0.$ [{\it Hint:} 
Let $h=(1-a)/a,$ and show that  $(1+h)^n\geq 1+nh.$]
\end{description}
```

the result is like this: 
[image]

How should I move the list up so that the (a) part is in the same line as 8?

Comment: Consider adding a little whitespace in your mathematics. It doesn't do anything in the output, but makes the source code much easier to read and helps with hard wrapping if your editor needs or wants that

Comment: You can also use `minipage` environment `\begin{minipage}[t]{<width>}...\end{minipage}` around `description` environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't hard code lists like this, if you want to change the style of an item label, use a package (or do it the hard way) to change the style of an item label.

Beyond that, the default behaviour of the `enumerate` environment gives you exactly the list structure that you want.

Here I use the `enumitem` package and pass the optional argument

```
[label=\textbf{\arabic*.},start=8]
```

to the enumerate environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\arabic*.},start=8]
  \item
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item
    Show that $\mathbb{R}$ has the greatest lower bound property.

    \item
    Show that $\inf\{1/n \mid n \in \mathbb{Z}_{+}\} = 0$.

    \item
    Show that given $a$ with $0 < a < 1$,
    $\inf\{a^{n} \mid n \in \mathbb{Z}_{+}\} = 0$. [\textit{Hint:} Let
    $h = (1 - a)/a$, and show that $(1 + h)^{n} \geq 1 + nh$.]
  \end{enumerate}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Also, please note, the `{\it foo}`, `{\bf foo}`, etc. syntax is some 20+ years deprecated. Please don't use it. Use `\textit{foo}`, `\textbf{foo}`, etc. or, if you prefer, `{\itshape foo}`, `{\bfseries foo}`, etc.